# Is there way to check wordpress logs? Like what actions admin has performed etc?

Tags: wordpress

hi friends Is there way to check wordpress logs? Like what actions admin has performed etc?
Actually I am working on a project and someone has deleted my pages templates to trash and my site was down. I want to check who did this in my wordpress admin panel?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't think Wordpress has an event log, at least I've never heard of one or seen one. There is a [login logger](http://www.cre8d-design.com/2007/07/wordpress-plugin-login-logger/) plugin, but it has to be installed and doesn't work retroactively.

In theory, it should be possible to get at least the IP address of the perpetrator from the normal Apache access logs, and searching it for all recent accesses to the `/wp-admin` folder. That is pretty cumbersome work, though.

Comment: may I ask you to have a look at a wordpress custom field related question here -  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43782429/wordpress-make-custom-field-values-clickable-to-retrive-them-later ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a plugin for this: try [Stream](https://wordpress.org/plugins/stream/) or its competitors.

Answer (score 0):

You may try this *[Activity Log](https://wordpress.org/plugins/aryo-activity-log/)* Plugin.

> If you have tens of users or more, you really can’t know who did what.
>   This plugin tries to solve this issue by tracking what users do, and
>   displaying it in an easy to use and easy to filter view on the
>   dashboard of your WordPress site.

Answer (score 0):

The following is not about action logs, but error logs, but it is also helpful. If that happened and you have WooCommerce installed, you will have access to logs:

```
Admin panel->WooCommerce->Status-> a tab: [Logs]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

My choice: [WP Admin Audit](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-admin-audit/)

From the WordPress.org listing:

> The modern activity log solution for WordPress
>
> WP Admin Audit is a powerful, modern monitoring log plugin for WordPress.
> Site owners and administrators can sleep better at night knowing the plugin keeps track of all site changes, security events, and admin activities.
>
> Ever wondered
>
> - who unpublished that blog post?
> - when the new media files were uploaded?
> - how that weird user account was created?
>
> The WordPress activity log in WP Admin Audit is your central hub to answer your questions.
> Keep track of everything that happens on your WordPress sites to:
>
> - Have a modern log of the changes done
> - Know about security-relevant activities
> - Find out who did what and at which time
> - Analyze the steps that led to a technical problem
> - Identify and mitigate automated login attempts by bots

It basically keeps track of all changes in your WordPress site. I like it!